# Android application crashes on insertion of element in ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am creating an application in which an item should be added to the ArrayList when button is clicked, but instead the app crashes. After debugging, I came to know that the statement **TaskList.add(td);** causes the application to crash. Please suggest how can I solve this?

The code is provided below:

**MainScreen.java:**

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


    View myView;

    public static TextView text_container;
    private RecyclerView list_container;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter list_container_adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager list_container_layout_manager;
    private static ArrayList<TaskData> TaskList = new ArrayList<TaskData>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
        list_container = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list_container);
        list_container.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list_container_layout_manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        list_container.setLayoutManager(list_container_layout_manager);
        list_container_adapter = new ListContainerAdapter(MainScreen.this,TaskList);
        list_container.setAdapter(list_container_adapter);
        list_container.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        TaskData td = new TaskData("Dhrumil",15,8,1997,12,30,5,"Academics",true);
        TaskList.add(td);
    }
```

TaskData.java:

```
public class TaskData {
    public String task,type;
    public int date,month,year,hour,minute,priority;
    public boolean alert;  

/*Getters and Setters are included in original code but not here due to longer length*/

    public TaskData(String task, int date, int month, int year, int hour, int minute, int priority, String type, boolean alert){
        this.task = task;
        this.date = date;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.type = type;
        this.alert = alert;
    }

}
```

**ListContainerAdapter.java:**

```
public class ListContainerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListContainerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<TaskData> TaskList;
    private String alertStatus;
    private Context context;
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView taskView,deadlineView,priorityView,typeView,alertStatusView;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            taskView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskView);
            deadlineView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.deadlineView);
            priorityView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
            typeView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.typeView);
            alertStatusView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.alertStatusView);
        }
    }

    public ListContainerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskData> TaskList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.TaskList = TaskList;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_container_element, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        TaskData taskData = TaskList.get(position);
        holder.taskView.setText(taskData.task);
        String newDate = taskData.date+"/"+taskData.month+"/"+taskData.year+"\t"+taskData.hour+":"+taskData.minute;
        holder.deadlineView.setText(newDate);
        holder.priorityView.setText(taskData.priority);
        holder.typeView.setText(taskData.type);
        if(taskData.alert){
            alertStatus = "ON";
        }
        else{
            alertStatus = "OFF";
        }
        holder.alertStatusView.setText(alertStatus);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return TaskList.size();
    }



}
```

**ERROR LOG:**

```
    --------- beginning of crash
07-03 17:04:13.675 2477-2477/com.bismuth.deadline E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bismuth.deadline, PID: 2477
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:335)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4555)
        at com.bismuth.deadline.ListContainerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ListContainerAdapter.java:53)
        at com.bismuth.deadline.ListContainerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ListContainerAdapter.java:13)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
07-03 17:04:13.677 1611-1625/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.bismuth.deadline/.MainScreen
```

Comment: post your error log here.

Comment: @mdhrumil what  exception your are getting?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit I have posted the crash report from the Logcat. Please have a look.

Comment: @AmitKumar Have a look at the crash report I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5

You are trying set `Int` value in `setText()` method

When you try to set `Int` in `setText()` method  it will take `int` value as `resource ID` and There is no `String resource` with such `int` value in `R.java` file so it will throw `Resources$NotFoundException`

So you need to convert that `int` in `string`

Use this

```
holder.priorityView.setText(String.valueOf(taskData.priority));
```

Instead of this

```
holder.priorityView.setText(taskData.priority);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are getting error because Your `Priority` field is `int` type. For setting `int` into `TextView` you have to convert `int` into `String`

Answer (score 1):

First of all please try to follow the naming conventions in java. In your code, the way you are trying to update the adapter is wrong. First you should create an instance of your adapter like this,

```
ListContainerAdapter adapter = new ListContainerAdapter(MainScreen.this,TaskList);
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Then in your adapter code, create a method like following,

```
public void updateAdapter(TaskData data){
this.arrayList.add(data)
notifyDatasetChanged()
}
```

Now whenever you need to update your adapter, call the following

```
TaskData data = TaskData()
adapter.updateAdapter(data)
```

and you are done.